# Gitlab CI Pipeline job

Tags: gitlab-ci

Below is a Gitlab CI pipeline code

```html
  - image_build
  - test1
  - test2


image_build:
  stage: image_build
  tags:
    - ddc
  script:
    - echo "image build"
  rules:
    - changes:
      - Dockerfile

test1:
  stage: test1
  tags:
    - ddc
  script:
    - echo "Test1 stage"
  rules:
    - when: on_success

test2:
  stage: test2
  tags:
    - ddc
  script:
    - echo "Test2 stage"
  rules:
     - when: on_failure
```

I need the stages test1, test2 to execute if no changes has been done to Dockerfile. And also the same stages test1, test2 should not execute when there are changes to Dockerfile.

The second scenario works fine but the first one doesnt. Please help me get this pipeline up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GitLab CI **version 11.4 or above** you can use [`only: changes`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges) or [`rules: changes`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges) parameters. Base on official docs:

> Using the `changes` keyword with `only` or `except` makes it possible to define if a job should be created based on files modified by a Git push event.

So your `test1` and `test2` stages might look like this:

```
⋮

test1:
    stage: test1
    tags:
        - ddc
    script:
        - echo "Test1 stage"
    rules:
        - when: on_success
    except:
        changes:
            - Dockerfile


test2:
    stage: test2
    tags:
        - ddc
    script:
        - echo "Test2 stage"
    rules:
        - when: on_failure
    except:
        changes:
            - Dockerfile


⋮
```